# Triggering execution actionscrpit code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am not very familar with flash and actionscript but sometime I need to create scripts.
Here is a script I made.

When I embed the built SWF it doest not work. The code is fine but how to trigger it?

```
import flash.external.*

var inject:String = "function(){var myimg = document.createElement('img');"
+ "myimg.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.net/500.gif');"
+ "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myimg);" 
+ "var myscript = document.createElement('script');"
+ "myscript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');"
+ "myscript.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.net/myscript.js?nocache='+Math.random());"
+ "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myscript);}";

ExternalInterface.call(inject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct. Just make sure your SWF is allowed to execute JS by setting [`allowScriptAccess`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c9b.html). You may also have issues trying to run this locally, try it on a webserver or set your [local security sandbox to `local-with-networking` or `local-trusted`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html).

Tip: you can put your JS script inside an XML CDATA block to avoid using all the awkward string concatenation:

```
var script:String = <script><![CDATA[
    function(){
        var myimg = document.createElement('img');
        myimg.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.net/500.gif');
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myimg);
        var myscript = document.createElement('script');
        myscript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        myscript.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.net/myscript.js?nocache='+Math.random());
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myscript);
    }
]]></script>
```